# Modifying a TLC mobile phase in order to increase the RF values

Tags: organic-chemistry, chromatography

You are running a TLC using 50% ethyl acetate in hexane and find the resulting $R_f$ values are too low. How would you modify the TLC mobile phase in order to increase the $R_f$ values?

Would the hexane and ethyl acetate be considered the mobile phase/solvent?

Comment: Increase the proportion of ethyl acetate

Comment: 50 vol% EA in hexanes already is pretty polar.  And yes, EA/hexanes is the mobile phase regardless how well the components of your analyte elute, or not -- this should be clear if engaging a TLC. Speculating you analyte is neither a low molecular weight carboxylic acid, phenol, primary amine (there is too few information provided by you), did you check the product is neutral (as in uncharged) and salt-free?

Comment: @Buttonwood really depends on what the substrate is. 1:1 Hexanes:EA is not to my mind particularly polar - that would be 7% MeOH in EA. It is worth running half a dozen trial mobile phases to see which one gives a decent separation.

Comment: @Waylander True, a high $R_f$ is not very useful if $\Delta{}R_f$ between the compounds of interest is little.

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Would the hexane and ethyl acetate be considered the mobile phase/solvent?

Answer is yes: Hexane/ethyl acetate systems ($0$ to $100\%$ ethyl acetate in hexane) are frequently used mobile phases for TLC technique. However, as Waylander pointed out in his comment:

> The type of mobile phase really depends on what the substrate and product are. It is worth running half a dozen trial mobile phases to see which one gives a decent separation.

Also, it is  true, as Buttonwood pointed out, a high $R_f$ value is not very useful if $\Delta R_f$ between the two compounds (or more in the mixture) of interest is small unless it increase upon change of mobile phase. For example, TLC of the mixture of benzoic acid and benzocaine (ethyl 4-aminobenzoate) shows no separation in $50\%$ ethyl acetate in hexanes. However, when mobile phase is change to $5\%$ methanol in dichloromethane, it has shown $\gt 33\%$ separation in $R_f$. So it is a trial and error method, but worth trying.